# SIMULINK treat constants as parameters or signals

Tags: parameters, signals, code-generation, simulink

I wanted to know if it is possible to enforce SIMULINK to consider my constants as parameters or signals in my model (when generating code).

For example, if I have a constant `a` that I want to be able to specify as a parameter (e.g. `int a`) instead of a signal (e.g. `int* a`). I know that simulink by default does everything in signal by default but there must be a way to configure it to do otherwise.

Does anyone know the way how to do it?

Kind Regards,

Comment: What is the problem you are facing with "int *a"? With "int *a" there should be some where in the code "a" gets assigned an address of "int a".

Comment: @Navan               It is not a problem, more like a preference. I have scheduler that dictates what sample rate I will be using. I don't want to hard code it in my SIMULINK model as a constant parameter. I want it to be loaded as a symbol externally (i.e. `extern float` or `extern int` declaration). I know that there is a way to do that in SIMULINK - Perhaps using `Load from Workspace` and specify in Workspace what the variable type is for the model (i.e. signal or parameter or constant)? Just assuming.

Comment: I think you need to look into `inline parameters` and then specify which parameters you do not wish to be inlined, and their respective storage class. See http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/inlining-parameters.html for more details.